# Conditionally ignoring a .dockerignore file on COPY

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, node-modules, glob

I have a front end build that uses variations of a Dockerfile for multiple steps: dev, CI (with Jenkins), and production. I'd like to not successively download node_modules for CI and production build images (both of which happen successively on the same box). Dev's node_modules are hosted on a volume to lower the overhead of restarting the dev container.

The three stages all share the same `.dockerignore` file which has a line excluding `node_modules`. Is it possible to add node_modules in  via something like `COPY node_modules/* node_modules/`? I've searched in vain for a way to use a bind mount during the build portion of both CI and production builds. This doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Can you use a different `Dockerfile` in the env where you want to `COPY node_modules/* node_modules/` ?

Comment: @vivekyad4v Yes, and that's already the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no such way where you can provide a different `.dockerignore` file.

As an alternative, you can copy the `node_modules` to a different directory such as `./node_new_module` using `cp` on the host OR probably integrate that `cp` command in your CI.

After that you can use the new `./node_new_module` to copy node modules in your Dockerfile -

`COPY ./node_new_modules/* node_modules/`

Hope this helps or gives you a way to solve this problem.